# PHP make an associative array from string of letters and numbers with the letters as index

Tags: php, arrays

I have strings of parameters which can vary in structure, and also vary in parameter order like this:

```
T01
T0101
T01C0.95
T01H3000C0.95(brackets indicate a comment
T01C0.95H3000(brackets indicate a comment
```

This needs to be made into an array like this:

```
T01H3000C0.95 or T01C0.95H3000
T01[H] = 3000
T01[C] = 0.95
ignore >(brackets indicate a comment
```

In the case that the T section is a length of 3 or 4 characters:

```
T0102H3000
"T"number1.number2[CP] = number3.number4
"T"number1.number2[H] = 3000
```

T will always be between 1 and 4 numbers long.
Periods . and spaces should not split the string.

The first section is easy because I know it will always start with T. So I can work with the string like this:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (substr( $line, 0, 1 ) === "T"){
    $lineArray = [];
         $trimedLine ="";
    print_r($line." - Tool Found");
    print_r("<br>");

    $trimedLine = ltrim($line, 'T');
    $lineArray = preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]/",$trimedLine,2);
    print_r("T - ".$lineArray[0]);
    print_r("<br>");    
    print_r("strlen: ".strlen($lineArray[0]));
    print_r("<br>");

    if (strlen($lineArray[0])== 1 OR strlen($lineArray[0])== 2){
     ${"T".$lineArray[0]}= [];
    print_r(${"T".$lineArray[0]});
    print_r("<br>");     
    } else {
    if (strlen($lineArray[0])== 3 OR strlen($lineArray[0])== 4)
    {   
    ${"T".$lineArray[0]}= [];   
    ${"T".$lineArray[0]}["CP"] = substr($lineArray[0], 2); 
    print_r(${"T".$lineArray[0]}["CP"]);
    print_r("<br>");        
    } else {
    print_r("Strange string size");
    print_r("<br>");    
    }
    }
    }
```

Afterwards it becomes more complicated. There is a chance that the index will be more than a single letter ex. SH or SP.

I could slowly cut the string down part by part by using something similar to my test code but it seems extremely convoluted.

How should I finish breaking this into an array?

Comment: I'd recommend using `explode()` to split the string. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I considered explodeing on A-Za-z but that would destroy the exploded charcter wouldn't it? I will add some more info to the question.

Comment: Please shows us the code you have already tried and what isn't working, so that we can help you fix it. Questions should show evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), Here is example to start with

[Demo](https://eval.in/886277)

```
<?php

$input='T01H3000C0.95(brackets indicate a comment';

/* from preg_replace above input we make 
   H=3000&C=0.95&, parse_str will put it in array
*/

parse_str( 
      preg_replace("/([A-Za-z])([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)/",'$1=$2&',
               preg_replace('/(^T01)|(\(.*)/','',$input) 
      ), 
      $array
);

print_r($array);


?>
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [H] => 3000
    [C] => 0.95
)
```

Comment: this answer looks promising. It should be safe to add the = and & to the string. parse_str() is the type of function I hoped existed. Does this pregex consider that there might be two letters instead of one? [SP] => 20

Comment: sorry I missed the example at the top. I tried myself and multiple letters works perfectly. I will try this way and accept the answer if it runs well. Thank you

Comment: This is tested now and can be adapted to work perfectly for my needs. Thank you for the help